# XML-comment: auto-generation

Tags: c#, monodevelop

I'm a C# developer for few years now. So, I've always code with Visual Studio.

But recently, I used MonoDevelop for a project and was totally amazed by the **XML comment auto-generation** possibility.

So, I'm wondering if there is this functionality for VS, or something similar.

Is it exist ?
Any ideas ?

Comment: Did you mean XMLDoc comment?If yes, you can generate it by using 3 slashes.

Comment: Have you read this: http://www.mono-project.com/Generating_Documentation ?

Comment: Yes, I mean XML doc comment, and thank you, I know about the 3 slashes. ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't compare it to MonoDevelop, but a pretty good similar tool for Visual Studio is [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx).

Comment: Yeah, that's great. Obviously, it's not as good as the similar tool in MonoDevelop (because, for example, in MonoDevelop, /// is enough, but not with GhostDoc that needs Shift+Ctrl+D) but that's what I was looking for. Thanks a lot !